# Why we cannot starting partition from the same side of the pivot in quicksort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm implementing quick sort using Hoare's partition method:

```
private static int partition(int[] arr, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    int pivot = arr[startIndex];
    int i = startIndex;
    int j = endIndex;
    while (i != j) {
        while (i < j && arr[i] <= pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (i < j && arr[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, startIndex, i);
    return i;
}
```

I choose the left element as pivot and starting from the left index, but I found this solution does not work. If I start from right it will work.

I want to know why we cannot start from the left index when the pivot is the leftmost element ?

Answer (score 0):

This variation of a post increment | post decrement Hoare partition scheme doesn't seem to have the issue:

```
void QuickSort(int *a, int lo, int hi)
{
int i, j;
int p, t;
    if(lo >= hi)
        return;
    p = a[lo + (hi-lo)/2];
    i = lo;
    j = hi;
    while (i <= j){
        while (a[i] < p)i++;
        while (a[j] > p)j--;
            if (i > j)
                break;
            t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
            i++;
            j--;
    }
    QuickSort(a, lo, j);
    QuickSort(a, i, hi);
}
```

---

Classic Hoare partition scheme uses pre-increment | post-increment and may fail with infinite recursion if the last element is used for pivot:

```
void QuickSort(int a[], int lo, int hi)
{
    if(lo >= hi)
        return;
    int p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
    int i = lo-1;
    int j = hi+1;
    while(1){
        while (a[++i] < p);
        while (a[--j] > p);
        if(i >= j)
            break;
        int t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    i = j++;
    QuickSort(a, lo, i);
    QuickSort(a, j, hi);
}
```

Comment: Ok because Cormen said if we can keep loop invariant then the loop should be correct, but the first case I showed above shows it's not correct

Comment: @hawarden_ - for the second example, classic Hoare partition, assume `hi` = `lo` + 1, and a[lo] < a[hi]. If `p = a[hi];` then `i` gets incremented, (`j` is unchanged), and the first recursive call `QuickSort(a, lo, i)` is the same as `QuickSort(a, lo, hi)`, getting stuck in infinite recursion.  Note that `p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];` rounds down so that if `hi` = `lo`+1, then `p = a[lo]`.